# Is it possible to find unmerged commits of the main branch and merge it to the root branch?

Tags: git

I am stuck in a messy situation. I have a main branch called develop which has commits from multiple different projects. I have a root branch which needs to catch up with the develop branch, the steps I follow are

1. Checkout develop branch
2. pull latest
3. Switch to the root branch
4. pull latest
5. clean, reset, clear nuget
6. merge develop into root branch

However, when I merge not all files that are different in both the branches show up in the 'unmerged conflicts' or 'staged files'. This leads to an erroneous merge.
I have merged from develop on different occasions earlier, this isn't the first time. But I believe there was a problem in the last merge that has led to this situation. I cannot rollback the last merge PR because that would cause more problems. I just want to know if there is a way to find unmerged commits of develop branch and merge them into my root branch to ensure all the different files between the branches have been addressed.

Comment: This is tagged C#. Is that because you are executing git commands from C# or your repository just happens to contain C# code?

Comment: you already made merge?

Comment: @gunr2171 the repository has C# code. Also, I merge using visual studio instead of using the git commands

Comment: @Iskander14yo  I've raised a dummy PR with the merge completed and I see build errors because of missing changes

Comment: Which errors do you get? root was created from develop or is completely independent?

Comment: @Iskander14yo It was created from develop. The errors say missing definition etc because the merge did not identify differences between the 2 branches correctly. For example, a method has been removed in a file on develop but still exists on root. The file that has this change is not captured during merge.

Comment: If you have performed a real merge, then there are no "unmerged" commits. To find "unmerged" commits, run `git log root..main` (shows all commits on main that haven't been merged to root). If you resolved conflicts incorrectly, then those commits are still "merged" and you need to figure out which changes are missing and then apply them.

Comment: @knittl meant unmerged conflicts before you complete the merge. Visual studio shows it as unmerged conflicts and staged changes, once the conflicts are resolved, the files get added to staged changes. Also, my problem is the changes are not showing up as conflicts in the first place but are supposed to show up.

Comment: **checkout** and **switch** are functionally the same exact command in most contexts like this. Is there a reason for making them distinct in your question?

Comment: @Caleb No sorry, I meant checkout in both cases

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had fallen a victim to similar problem like yours. I tried the following steps to solve the issue:

1. Make sure you are on the **root** branch (as you want the **develop** branch commits here)

   **git checkout root**
2. Pull the latest changes from the remote repository toensure you have the latest code

   **git pull origin root**
3. Checkout the develop branch

   **git checkout develop**
4. Pull the latest changes from the develop branch

   **git pull origin develop**
5. Rebase your root branch on the latest develop changes.This will apply the unmerged commit sfrom develop to your root branch:

   **git rebase develop**
6. There are chances that there will be conflicts after the rebase. Resolve them (git will ask you if you want to resolve them)
7. After resolving continue the rebase command again

   **git rebase --continue**
8. After rebase completes you should have all the unmerged commits from develop integrated into your root branch.
9. push the changes to remote repository

   **git push origin root**

I heard that making a backup or creating new branch is recomended in case anything goes wrong during the rebase to avoid data loss.